# NPM 7 workspaces - how to install new package in workspace?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

If I have a [NPM 7 workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) like this:

```
root
   - submodule0
   - submodule1
   - submodule2
```

and I navigate to the submodule0 directory and run `npm i somepackage` it seems to "break" the workspace by creating a new package-lock.json in the submodule0 directory and installing all the dependencies there.  In other words, it just does the old behavior that existed before I created the workspace.
I was hoping for a command similar to [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/add) where I can install a new package in submodule0 from the **root**.  Something like:

```
npm i somepackage --scope submodule0
```

So far, the only workaround I can find is to edit the submodule0 package.json and add the `somepackage` manually.  Then run `npm i` from the root.  Obviously this is not ideal because I need to look up the @latest version, navigate to the subdirectory, open the package.json, etc. etc. as opposed to just typing one line in the root.

Comment: I have the same question

Comment: Did you try going to the root of workspace and doing npm update?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Workspace support for `npm install` and `npm uninstall` was added in npm v7.14.0. You can now just do:

```
npm i somepackage --workspace=submodule0
```

Uninstalling modules has been the biggest pain, so this is really exciting. The npm team seems to be slowly adding support to commands one by one. Follow updates here: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md.

Comment: My project was setup to use yarn instead, and `yarn add package-name` worked

Comment: and for multiple: npm i somepackage --workspace=submodule0 --workspace=submodile1.

Comment: what about all workspaces?

Comment: is it possible to install workspace + root packages at same time?

Answer (score 11):

I'm also baffled with why npm workspaces has been released without this functionality.

My current workaround uses the [add-dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-dependencies) package, which adds dependencies to a declared package.json file, whilst skipping the installation process.

```
npm i add-dependencies -g
```

Then, from top level of the monorepo, you can run:

```
npx add-dependencies ./submodule0/package.json somepackage && npm i
```

Hopefully a `--workspace` argument will be added to `npm i` soon to avoid this faff.

Comment: This is a really useful suggestion.  I think I might be able to get it down to one npm script in the root by using this (although I might have to use JS to make it OS agnostic).  If I do that, I'll return and include that here.

Answer (score 11):

Please refer to the answer of mattwad above if you have NPM v7.14.0 or above

**Original answer**

I wasn't quite happy with the suggestions, but combined all of them to use it in a npm script without any dependencies:

```
{
   "add": "npm install --package-lock-only --no-package-lock --prefix",
   "postadd": "npm install"
}
```

This can be used like following: `npm run add -- submodule0 somepackage`

Answer (score 3):

### Add only into package.json

U can use this to install package only into package.json ( you don't need external dependencies )

```
npm i --prefix packages/test --save --package-lock-only --no-package-lock express
```

followed by `npm i` to install specified dependency into mono repository root node_modules

### Lerna

Also can use [lerna](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna) to use workspace name to install dependency into

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mono",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
     "wsi": "function workspaceinstall() { ( scope=$1; shift; lerna exec --scope \"$scope\" -- npm install --package-lock-only --no-package-lock \"$@\") }; workspaceinstall"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

`lerna.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "packages": ["packages/**"]
}
```

```
npm run wsi [workspace name] [dependency name to install]
npm run wsi @workspace/test express
npm run wsi @workspace/test express --save-prod 
npm run wsi @workspace/test @types/express --save-dev
```

wsi script only modify package.json for provided workspace name, to actually install dependencies u have to run `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, which is similar to yours, I deleted all dependencies from all the inner projects, deleted also the package-lock.json, and installed everything in the root.

```
/
  node_modules
  package.json >> all dependencies
  package-lock.json >> the only lock file that exists in the repo
  /packages
    /A
      package.json >> no dependencies
      -- no package-lock.json
    /B
      package.json >> no dependencies
      -- no package-lock.json
    /C
      package.json >> no dependencies
      -- no package-lock.json
```

This way, the node_modules folder ONLY resides on the root, and also the package-lock.json file is in the root.

If I allowed to have each project it's own package-lock.json I started seeing installation and runtime errors (because each project could have its own node_modules and its own version of a dependency).

This is the best way I see it works.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what you are using workspaces for if you're doing this? What you've suggested will work, but unless I've missed something, it sounds to me it like you're treating workspaces as not workspaces?

Comment: sure, C is a common package where I have all my service classes, while A and B are apis that have the koa endpoint router configuration which reuse the services written in C. Before, I had to republish C everytime to private npm to install in A and B. Now, I can refer C without any install.

Answer (score 1):

i believe that this behavior has been fixed in npm 8.5.0.

- changelog: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/changelog#v850-2022-02-10
- commit: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/4372

i was able to install a package in the `submodule0` workspace from the `submodule0/` directory without it creating a `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/` in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to use the `npm install` with the `--prefix --save --package-lock-only --no-package-lock` options, npm always give the the error `E404 - Not Found` for my own packages of the monorepo that are not yet published to a registry. So even when trying to install external packages it fails because of my current dependencies in the package.json.

To workaround this issue I ended up with a mix of the previous suggestions:

```
"scripts": {
    "add": "add-dependencies $npm_config_scope/package.json",
    "postadd": "npm i",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "add-dependencies": "^1.1.0"
},
```

Then I can do:

```
npm run add --scope=packages/app express
npm run add --scope=packages/core eslint jest -D
```

This works fine for installing external packages. To install my own packages that lives inside the monorepo, I still have to manually edit the package.json, otherwise I get the `package not found error`.

Comment: It'd be better if you could add some explanation of how and why this works, while others did not.